# during ajax processing when we click ouside of popup then popup should not be closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, codeigniter

I am doing ajax functionlity on popup, during ajax functionality when we click outside of popup then popup should not be closed

I am using..

```
$('.edits-photo').modal('toggle');
```

so please suggest me the changes.

Comment: Instead of toggle you can use $('.edits-photo').modal('show'); and $('.edits-photo').modal('hide');

Answer (score 0):

Try like below:

```
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
    $(".edits-photo").modal({
      escapeClose: false,
      clickClose: false,
      showClose: false
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you check this answer? @Webizz Technosoft